# Can I run these two Graphics Cards at the same time

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

So, I'm upgrading my computer and I have two graphics cards, one RTX 570 and one GTX 1650, Could I use them both at the same time on windows 10?

Comment: Can you run them for what purpose?  That’s important...SLI won’t be possible but multiple GPU with DX12 will be possible.  However, you won’t get a great deal of performance gains, from that older hardware

Answer (score 0):

You may install the two cards in one computer, but only one will be used
with the display.

For other uses, for example bitcoin mining, the second (non-main) one will be
too weak to be useful.
You can configure one to run non-demanding tasks with an automatic switch
to the other one for demanding tasks, but I don't think that this would
help much.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have two slots to take the cards, you can install two video cards. If you want to do SLI/Crossfire, then they’ll need to be a matching pair (at least the same model, not necessarily the same manufacturer) and have the connectors to do this. (Cheap cards don’t.)